# Creating a Roster Database in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am dealing with a roster with 15,000 unique employees. Depending on their 'Designation' they either impact performance or do not. The issue is, these employees could change their designation any day. The roster is as simple as this:
AgentID
AgentDesignation
Date

I feel like I would be violating some Normalization rules if I just have duplicate values (the agent has the same designation from the previous day, for example). Would I really want to create a new row for each date even if the Designation is the same? I want to always be able to get the agent's correct designation on a particular date.

All calculations are done with Excel, probably with Vlookup. Anyone have some tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table structure you propose would not be a violation of normalization -- it contains a PRIMARY KEY (AgentID, Date) and a single attribute that is dependent on all elements of the key (AgentDesignation).  Furthermore, it's easy (using the PRIMARY KEY constraint) to ensure that there is one-and-only-one designation per agent per day.  The fact that many PRIMARY KEY values will yield the same dependent value does not mean the database is not correctly normalized.

An alternative approach using date ranges would likely result in fewer rows but guaranteeing integrity would be harder and searches for a particular value would be costlier.

Comment: So would this be CREATE TABLE roster (PRIMARY KEY (Date, AgentID), Designation);

Comment: That is not valid SQL.  You need to list the columns first, then a PRIMARY KEY specifier.  Something like `CREATE TABLE roster (Date, AgentID, Designation, PRIMARY KEY (Date, AgentID));` but check the exact syntax with the SQLite documentation.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Thanks so much